# Separating same kind of element by a comma

Tags: html, xml, formatting, xquery

I have this xquery for a collection of books, which individually have 1 or more fagfelt(topics) each. When i run my query all the topics are grouped up in one cell of the table (I want this), but they are not easily separated

```
let $books := (doc("oblig3.xml")/bøker/bok)
return 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>Fagfelt</tr><hr/>
        <tr><td><b>Bok Title</b></td>
        <td><b>Forfatter</b></td>
        <td colspan="3"><b>Fagfelt</b></td>
    </tr>
{
    for $x in $books
    order by $x/tittle
    return <tr>
        <td>{data($x/tittle)}</td>
        <td>{data($x/forfatter)}</td>
        <td>{data($x/fagfelt)}</td>
    </tr>   
} 
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Example of a return I get is -

```
<td>Filosofi Kunnskapsrepresentasjon Kunstig Intelligens Programmering</td>
```

Which is 4 topics in one, not very easy to read.  How can I separate these and make it look more like

```
<td>Filosofi, Kunnskapsrepresentasjon, Kunstig Intelligens, Programmering</td>
```

Preferably within the same cell, I have tried just listing them with

```
{data($x/fagfelt[1...4]/text())},
```

And doing the separation manually, but that just leaves a lot of commas at the end of books with just 1 topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you serialize a sequence to a string in XQuery, the defined behavior is to return a space-delimited list. However, if you want to use a custom delimiter, use `fn:string-join()`:

```
fn:string-join($x/fagfelt, ', ')
```

From the W3C specification:

> Each enclosed expression is converted to a string as follows:
>
> a.  Atomization is applied to the value of the enclosed expression, converting it to a sequence of atomic values.
>
> b.  If the result of atomization is an empty sequence, the result is the zero-length string. Otherwise, each atomic value in the atomized sequence is cast into a string.
>
> c.  The individual strings resulting from the previous step are merged into a single string by concatenating them with a single space character between each pair.

Comment: Thanks alot, ended up using <td>{string-join((data($x/fagfelt)),", ")}</td> which fixed it